# An almost sure convergence problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \longrightarrow x_0$ almost surely, where $x_0\in [\alpha, 1-\alpha]$ and $0<\alpha<1$. I'm trying to show that for all $\epsilon >0$, 
$$
P\left(|X_n - x_0|> \frac{\alpha}{2}\right) < \epsilon\quad\quad (*)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

My attempt: since $X\longrightarrow x_0$ a.s, we have for all $\epsilon'>0$ and $\epsilon >0$, $\forall n\ge n_{\epsilon'}$
$$
P\left(|X_n - x_0| > \epsilon' \right) < \epsilon  
$$
Then we choose $\epsilon' = \alpha/2$ and we will get $(*)$. The solution is quite simple but I'm not sure! What do you think about this? Thank you for any comment or suggestion.

Comment: It looks like you want to show that $X_n\rightarrow x_0$ in probability. Now your attempt amounts to just stating the classical property that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability - hence it is correct but you don't really present an argument. Apart from that, I'm a bit confused about the setting: For the argument, it is not important that $x_0$ is deterministic nor that there is a relation between $x_0$ and $\alpha$. Where do these assumptions come from?

Comment: @ Mau314: Thank you for your comment. These assumptions are just the constraints in an exercice.